# How to Uninstall this Trotux from my Windows 8 PC?

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome, taskbar, adware

Recently I downloaded an application (I suppose its iPadian emulator from a third party website), the website gave me an online installer which not only downloaded the emulator but also a bunch of unwanted applications and one of them was "Trotux". By a simple google search I came to know that it is an adware so I downloaded Malwarebytes AdwCleaner and ran a scan. The cleaner found out some issues and cleaned them for me but it was unable to detect Trotux at all. I even tried re-installing chrome after uninstalling it, but still that trotux is not willing to leave. here are some issues I face (better to say changes to my chrome which I face)

I have pinned the chrome icon on my taskbar but when I click to open it a completely new icon pops up (the one at far right in the picture below)
[image: Taskbar]

Again when I open chrome it seems that somethings have changed like I have been automatically logged out, new extensions are automatically added, and the user option at the title bar has changed to 'user0'. See the picture below.
[image: Chrome schreenshot]

The trotux shows itself under the control panel's uninstall section but when I click it nothing happens. See below.
[image: Control panel]

So please help me, I feel that trotux may fiddle with the private informations that I share with my browser (passwords etc. though I haven't saved any but I fear when I login again to some website my creds can get hijaked).

Comment: Looks like the software was gone but the cleaner did a bad job, manually go through registry, and remove its entries.  Chrome issue, switch user and/or delete chrome profile to nuke any traces

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks a lot. I never thought of deleting registry keys myself. I am going to try that out now.